# Jquery Datepicker beforeShowDay not displaying tooltip and not assigning class in return

Tags: jquery, datepicker, tooltip, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to color the background of certain days in an embedded datepicker (not in an input field) and fire a tooltip on hover on those same colored days but is not doing anything. I checked in the console and the tooltips messages are there but not in the calendar, and also the background color is not been applied. I tried just applying a background color without the tooltip using only 'return {Classes: "activeClass"}' and it works but is not what I need. Any help is very much appreciated.

The date arrays and text for the tooltips are been generating with PHP.

Here is my code:

```
    <style>
        .activeClass{
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #339966; 
        }        
    </style>

    <script>
        var active_dates = ["4/10/2022", "5/1/2022", "5/29/2022", "6/26/2022", "7/10/2022", "7/24/2022", "8/7/2022", "8/21/2022", "9/11/2022", "9/25/2022", "10/9/2022", "10/16/2022", "11/6/2022", "12/25/2022", ]; 
        var tooltips = [];
        tooltips[new Date('4/10/2022')] = 'DBL: 1689.00/ TWN: 1689.00'; tooltips[new Date('5/1/2022')] = 'DBL: 1729.00/ TWN: 1729.00'; tooltips[new Date('5/29/2022')] = 'DBL: 1799.00/ TWN: 1799.00'; tooltips[new Date('6/26/2022')] = 'DBL: 1799.00/ TWN: 1799.00'; tooltips[new Date('7/10/2022')] = 'DBL: 1799.00/ TWN: 1799.00'; tooltips[new Date('7/24/2022')] = 'DBL: 1799.00/ TWN: 1799.00'; tooltips[new Date('8/7/2022')] = 'DBL: 1799.00/ TWN: 1799.00'; tooltips[new Date('8/21/2022')] = 'DBL: 1799.00/ TWN: 1799.00'; tooltips[new Date('9/11/2022')] = 'DBL: 1729.00/ TWN: 1729.00'; tooltips[new Date('9/25/2022')] = 'DBL: 1729.00/ TWN: 1729.00'; tooltips[new Date('10/9/2022')] = 'DBL: 1689.00/ TWN: 1689.00'; tooltips[new Date('10/16/2022')] = 'DBL: 1689.00/ TWN: 1689.00'; tooltips[new Date('11/6/2022')] = 'DBL: 1689.00/ TWN: 1689.00'; tooltips[new Date('12/25/2022')] = 'DBL: 1689.00/ TWN: 1689.00';  
        var date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
        $('#date_pick').datepicker({     
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            startDate: date,
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            todayHighlight: false,
            beforeShowDay: function(date){
                var d = date;
                var curr_date = d.getDate();
                var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
                var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
                var formattedDate = curr_month + "/" + curr_date + "/" + curr_year
                if ($.inArray(formattedDate, active_dates) != -1){

                    var tooltip = tooltips[date]; 
                    return [true, "activeClass",tooltip],
                    console.log(tooltip);

                }
                return;
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `,` at the end of the `return [true, "activeClass",tooltip]` line instead of a `;`. First fix that as it may cause the issue...